# dynamically create callback functions inside a for loop

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am creating a plugin to handle woocommerce product tabs.

I load the new custom tabs by hooking into `woocommerce_product_tabs`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'benz_new_product_tabs' );
```

I then have a function to load the tab titles based on a DB meta_value - everything is working fine.  -- I have deleted most of the stuff to spare you - but tried to keep everything that is important, relevant.

```
function benz_new_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
  global $post;
  $benz_tab_count = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tabs_total_number', true );
  for ( $x = 0; $x < $benz_tab_count; $x++ ) {
    $y=$x+1;
    $benz_tab_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_tabs_title_$y", true );
    $benz_tab_title_clean = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $benz_tab_title);

    if ( strlen($benz_tab_title) > 0  ) {
      $tabs[$benz_tab_title_clean] = array(
        'title'     => __( $benz_tab_title, 'woocommerce' ),
        'priority'  => $y+50,
        'callback'  => 'benz_new_product_tab_content'.$y
      );
    } // end foreach
  }
  return $tabs;
}
```

So - this generates as many tab titles as needed per db table and assigns a unique callback function to then provide content for each tab.

The call back functions are what I am struggling with. I would like to create a loop that will generate each callback function and the relevant content.

The following functions are working fine - but i would really like to make this smarter, if possible.

```
function benz_new_product_tab_content1() {
  global $post;
   $benz_tab_content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_tabs_content_1", true );
   if (strlen($benz_tab_content) > 0) {
     echo $benz_tab_content;
   }
}

function benz_new_product_tab_content2() {
  global $post;
   $benz_tab_content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_tabs_content_2", true );
   if (strlen($benz_tab_content) > 0) {
     echo $benz_tab_content;
   }
}

function benz_new_product_tab_content3() {
  global $post;
   $benz_tab_content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_tabs_content_3", true );
   if (strlen($benz_tab_content) > 0) {
     echo $benz_tab_content;
   }
}
```

I have more than 3 tabs on many of my products, sometimes as much as 8 ( per client ) so I have that block of call back functions pasted 8 times in my plugin file. 
I have tried to put it in a for loop - but obviously, you cant concatenate a variable onto the end of a function name.

Let me know your thoughts, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do it with args:

```
'callback' => benz_new_product_tab_content,
'args' => '_tabs_content_' . $y
```

And your function:

```
function benz_new_product_tab_content($param, $args) { 
  global $post; 
  $table = end($args); 
  $benz_tab_content = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $table, true ); 

  if (strlen($benz_tab_content) > 0) { 
    echo $benz_tab_content; 
  } 
}
```

---

One alternative is to create anonymous function like this:

```
  'callback' => function() { // do your work }
```

Typically to create functions in `FOR` loop you would use `eval`. I think this is not the smart choice.

Comment: @RobBenz edit done.

Comment: No problem. You may edit this code further if you have something to add.